# Locked myself out of Amazon EC2 SSH - This service allows sftp connections only

Tags: ssh, sshd, putty

Doh.

Locked myself out of SSH on an Amazon EC2 box after fiddling with 
`ForceCommand internal-sftp` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in order to allow `root` log-in via SFTP.

SFTP still works fine, but PuTTY dies instantly, e.g:

[image: PuTTY]

The odd thing here is that SFTP still works fine and permits me to log-in as `root` currently (because of the changes I made) - so I've got a WinSCP window open and I can trawl through whatever I like and edit stuff.

When I try to connect from another Linux box using:

```
ssh -i keyfile.pem ec2-user@hostname.com.au -p [portnumber]
```

I get the following response:

```
This service allows sftp connections only.
Connection to [hostname] closed.
```

I've successfully removed `ForceCommand internal-sftp` from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but I'm having trouble running `service ssh restart` remotely. When I do it from `sftp` with the `!` prefix, it says it's worked - but I can tell that it hasn't because the listening port is not changing.

Comment: Why would you need to *obviously* obfuscate your actual keys in `authorized_keys`? They should be your public keys not your private keys.

Comment: from the evidence you give it is not a key problem. From your evidence in your update, it looks like you have changed the configuration to allow sftp only, not shell login.

Comment: @Emmanuel the evidence does not suggest that it is an authentication problem.

Comment: `ForceCommand internal-sftp` is not needed for `sftp` to work, but it will stop shell login. Have you restarted `sshd` after fixing `sshd_config`?

Comment: `authorised_keys` is fine: you have no configuration fields, and if sftp works then the key is ok.

Comment: Agreed. I removed `ForceCommand internal-sftp` from `sshd_config` altogether and sort of awkwardly remotely restarted `sshd` by doing `system("service sshd restart");` via a PHP script. It's still displaying the same error message after doing so (which is odd). I've even tried replacing `sshd_config` with a 'known working' sshd_config from another system and no dice. Normally I would suspect that `sshd` is in fact not restarting at all, but when I changed the `ServerPort` and restarted it with this method - it changed SSH's listening port number correctly. Hmmmm.

Comment: After some further investigation, I have come to the conclusion that sshd is definitely not restarting, despite the fact that PHP is reporting the following: `Stopping sshd: [FAILED] Starting sshd: [ OK ]`. I'm guessing this is because Apache doesn't have privileges to run `service sshd restart`. Given that I don't have SSH and only SFTP access - is there any way I can restart SSH remotely or get the config to refresh? I guess a reboot would _probably_ do the trick but I'm also a little nervous about the idea that SFTP might not work when it comes back up.

Comment: @josten Yep. That's my fall back position if all else fails.

Comment: Rebooted the server and I'm back in SSH! Hooray :)

Comment: @richard suspicion was on the sshd not to be restarted,  Sftp as root was sure while the old conf was active and there was no evidence he can log with another user after the restart as he put "permitrootlogin no" back in the conf (as mentioned before it was removed at last edit). Thats why I asked to validate first an sftp connection as ec2user.

Comment: There is no way that php should be able to restart the service, you need root for that, and apache and php should not be running as root. (also not your error message: it says `stopping sshd: [FAILED]`. It succeeded in starting, because the post condition for start is started.

Answer (score 6):

Removed `ForceCommand internal-sftp` from `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and rebooted the server (to refresh the configuration file) and I'm back in.

Comment: This worked fine for me too.. But I got one more error that is throwing me out of PUTTY.. '/bin/bash: No such file or directory', What could be causing this issue? any idea?

Answer (score 1):

> When I do it from `sftp` with the `!` prefix, it says it's worked

It has! But `!` executes the command on the client, not on the server. So watch out for what you may inadvertently have changed on the client.

The SFTP protocol deliberately doesn't allow the client to specify commands to run on the server. It's only a file transfer protocol.

You may however indirectly trigger commands on the server by writing them to a file that will be executed. For example, you can drop an at job in `/var/spool/cron/atjobs` (if you know what to write in the job file and in the `.SEQ` file — the at spool format isn't completely trivial). You can edit `/etc/crontab` or some other crontab. Usually SFTP-only users are confined to their home directory, but with root access to the whole filesystem, SFTP without full SSH access doesn't actually provide any security, just inconvenience.

Thus:

1. Use `sftp` to download `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and `/etc/crontab`.
2. Edit the downloaded files to remove the `ForceCommand` line and add a cron job that runs `service ssh restart` (or `/etc/init.d/ssh restart` or whatever your init system wants) as root.
3. Use `sftp` to upload the modified files.
4. Wait for the cron job to trigger.
5. Use `ssh` to log in and edit out the temporary cron job.